# Irreducible markov chain problem

Tags: self-study, markov-process

Let $P$ be a stationary transition probability matrix of the markov chain $ \{X_n , n \ge 0\}, $ which is irreducible and every state has a period 2. Further suppose that the markov chain $\{Y_n , n \ge 0\}$ on the same state space has transition probability matrix $P^2$ . Both chains are assumed to have the same initial distributions.

then state how the chain $\{Y_n , n \ge 0\} $ is irreducible  ?

i am very new to the concept of markov chains and found this question beyond my level , please tell how and why $\{Y_n , n \ge 0\} $ should be irreducible ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out proposition 5.4.3 on page 119 of [Meyn and Tweedie](http://probability.ca/MT/BOOK.pdf). If you sample an irreducible chain at its period, the resulting chain is irreducible **only when you restrict the state space to a cyclic class.** What’s more is that these cyclic classes are absorbing, so with every step of the sampled chain, it stays in there with probability 1. The counterexample mentioned in the comment is a perfect example of this: the one-step 2x2 transition matrix with zeroes on the diagonal and ones on the off-diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

A markov chain is irreducible if it is possible to get to any state from any state. The fact that $\{X_n,n\geq 0\}$ is periodic of period $2,$ let me think, $\{Y_n,n\geq 0\}$ is not irreductible

In fact, for two states $i,j$, there exists $n>0$, such as $p_{ij}^{(n)} = \mathbb{P}(X_n=j\mid X_0=i) = (P^n)_{ij} > 0.$

As $\{X_n,n\geq 0\}$ is periodic of period $2,$ $\mathbb{P}(X_2=i\mid X_0=i)>0$

if $n=2k$ is even $p_{ij}^{(n)}=(P^n)_{ij} = (P^{2k})_{ij} = \left((P^2)^{k}\right)_{ij} = \mathbb{P}(Y_k=j\mid Y_0=i) > 0.$

if $n=2k+1$ is odd fail to prove that.

Comment: I agree to your facts but then why this counter example comes ?            $let P=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$,  this irreducible  

but then $P^2=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ is not irreducible

Comment: That's right, $n$ will always be odd. And when $n$ is odd, ${Y_n, n\eq 0\}$ can not be irréductible. Maybe it's not true. But I fail to prove that

Comment: Just because a chain has period two doesn’t mean that it’s possible to return to places in two steps.

Comment: It mean the gcd of the possible times of step you can return is two. In other word, you can return only in 2, 4, 6, ... step.

Comment: @AbdoulHaki or 4,6,...